# html 5 slider onhange/input not triggered when setting value in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, slider

I have the following html 5 slider and button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default zhaw-ict-icon zhaw-icon-hinzufugen zoom-in" (click)="zoomIn()"></button>
<input class="btn zoom" type="range" min="1" max="300" [value]="currentZoomValue" 
      (change)="zoomWithRangeInput($event)"
      (input)="zoomWithRangeInput($event)"
```

Here is the typescript

```
zoomIn(): void {
    this.currentZoomValue = 20;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

If I manually drag the slider everything works as expected.
If I click the button and update `currentZoomValue` in the method `zoomIn` the method `zoomWithRangeInput`is never called because neither the `input` nor the `change` event get called. But `currentZoomValue` has the correct value of 20 and the slider has moved to reflect 20.

Any idea what might cause that or is that expected behavior?

Comment: What are you trying to achive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to your problem is :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default zhaw-ict-icon zhaw-icon-hinzufugen zoom-in" (click)="zoomIn()"></button>
<input class="btn zoom" type="range" min="1" max="300" [value]="currentZoomValue" 
      (change)="zoomWithRangeInput($event.target.value)"
      (input)="zoomWithRangeInput($event.target.value)"
```

In type script :

```
zoomIn(): void {
    this.currentZoomValue = 20;
    this.zoomWithRangeInput(this.currentZoomValue);
}
....
zoomWithRangeInput(value)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: yes, that is what had in mind as fallback, but unfortunately doesn't answer the question why the events aren't called.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the model value instead. Use `ngModelChange` and set value also in `ngModel`:

```
<input class="btn zoom" type="range" min="1" max="300" [value]="currentZoomValue" 
      (ngModelChange)="zoomWithRangeInput($event)" [(ngModel)]="currentZoomValue" />
```

Comment: this doesnt change the behavior

Comment: @Arikael change my `onRangeModelChange` to your `zoomWithRangeInput` . check my updated answer. `zoomWithRangeInput` will pass you the updated value which you can set in your component.

Comment: sorry, didn't mention, but I did change the method names